# Large fonts on canvas take long time in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, fonts, size

has anyone noticed or found a solution to the problem I've been experiencing? It takes a long time to render large fonts (>100px) in Chrome on the canvas using fillText(). I need to have a much faster frame rate, but once the fonts get big it take like a second to load each frame. In firefox it runs well though...

UPDATE:

Here is the pertinent code that is running in my draw() function which runs every 10 milliseconds on interval. If anything pops out to you, that would be great. I'll try to profiler thing though, thanks.

```
 g.font = Math.floor(zoom) + "px sans-serif";
    g.fillStyle = "rgba(233,233,245," + (ZOOM_MAX-zoom*(zoom*0.01))/(ZOOM_MAX) + ")";
    for (h=0; h<76; h++)
    {
        h_offset = 2.75*h*Math.floor(zoom);

        // only render if will be visible, because it tends to lag; especially in Chrome
        hpos = Math.floor(half_width + std_offset + h_offset);

        if (hpos > (-half_width)-h_offset && hpos < WIDTH+h_offset)
        {
            g.fillText(1950+h, hpos, anchor_y - 0);
        }
    }

    g.font = "600 " + Math.floor(zoom/40) + "px sans-serif";
    g.fillStyle = "rgba(233,233,245," + (ZOOM_MAX-zoom*(zoom*0.0001))/(ZOOM_MAX) + ")";
    for (h=0; h<76; h++)
    {
        h_offset = 2.75*h*Math.floor(zoom);

        hpos = Math.floor(half_width + std_offset + h_offset);

        if (hpos > (-half_width)-h_offset && hpos < WIDTH+h_offset)
        {                
            // see if we should bother showing months (or will it be too small anyways)
            if (zoom/40 > 2)
            {
                // show months
                for (i=0; i<12; i++)
                {
                    i_offset = 0.175*i*zoom;
                    ipos = Math.floor(WIDTH/2 + std_offset + i_offset + h_offset) + 10;

                    if (ipos > -half_width && ipos < WIDTH)
                    {
                        g.fillText(months[i], ipos, anchor_y - 20);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    g.font = "600 " + Math.floor(zoom/350) + "px sans-serif";
    g.fillStyle = "rgba(233,233,245," + (ZOOM_MAX-zoom/5)/(ZOOM_MAX*2.25) + ")";
    for (h=0; h<76; h++)
    {
        h_offset = 2.75*h*Math.floor(zoom);

        // only render if will be visible, because it tends to lag; especially in Chrome
        hpos = Math.floor(half_width + std_offset + h_offset);

        if (hpos > (-half_width)-h_offset && hpos < WIDTH+h_offset)
        {                
            // see if we should bother showing months (or will it be too small anyways)
            if (zoom/40 > 2)
            {
                // show months
                for (i=0; i<12; i++)
                {
                    i_offset = 0.175*i*zoom;
                    ipos = Math.floor(WIDTH/2 + std_offset + i_offset + h_offset) + 10;

                    // see if we should bother showing days (or will it be too small anyways)
                    if (zoom/350 > 2)
                    {
                        // show days
                        for (j=0; j<31; j++)
                        {
                            j_offset = 0.005*j*zoom + zoom*0.005;
                            jpos = Math.floor(half_width + std_offset + j_offset + i_offset + h_offset);

                            if (jpos > -half_width && jpos < WIDTH)
                            {
                                g.fillText(days[i][j], jpos, anchor_y - 20);
                                selected_days += 'm: '+i+', d: '+j+' | ';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

We'd need a lot more information, I'm not convinced that *drawing* a large font is actually whats causing the performance issues. Drawing such a large font works extremely quickly on my machines for any browser that I've tried.

The first thing you should do is open up the Chrome profiler and then run the code, and see if it is actually the `ctx.fillText` call that is taking up the time. I imagine its actually something else.

It's possible you are calling something too much, like setting `ctx.font` over and over unnecessarily. Setting `ctx.font` on some browsers actually takes significantly longer to do than calls to `fillRect`! If your font changes in the app you can always cache.

Here's a test back from October: http://jsperf.com/set-font-perf

As you can see, in many versions of Chrome setting the font unnecessarily doubles the time it takes! So make sure you set it as little as possible (with caching, etc).